# maximizing log likelihood with missing variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data, likelihood

Suppose I have data $(x_{it},y_t)_{i=1,t=1}^{N,T}$, where $N\rightarrow \infty$ and $T<\infty$. My likelihood function for $i$ will be
$f(x_{it},y_t;\theta_0)$ where $\theta_0$ is the parameter. Then, under some regularity conditions, I can consistently estimate $\theta_0$ by maximzing
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{t=1}^T \log f(x_{it},y_t;\theta)
\end{equation}
over $\theta$. I denote this log-likelihood estimator by $\hat{\theta}_1$

Now, Suppose I only observe $(x_{it})_{i=1,t=1}^{N,T}$, then my log likelihood function becomes
$$\sum_t \log \int \prod_{i}f(x_{it},y;\theta)\,dy $$
Then, I try to estimate $\theta_0$ by maximizing the above log likelihood function. I denote this log-likelihood estimator by $\hat{\theta}_2$.

I wonder if I can consistently estimate $\theta_0$ using $\hat{\theta}_2$. I would like to know a very detailed theorem and proof, I could not find any reference for this.

1. I assume identification is guaranteed from the second likelihood function.
2. I am not sure how I can argue asymptotic here. I am not sure what would happened if $N\rightarrow \infty$.